# selenium is not locating chromedriver.exe

Tags: java

I have added necessary jars. My code is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Felight/Eclipse/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

the above code is not executing.shows "unknown source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links will help you:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Please download the respective driver exe and follow the instructions.